# How to CloudDeploy an API and then use curl?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, api

I'd like to see a single example of APIFunction deployed that is accessible via curl, not a web browser.

For example:

```
func = APIFunction[{"x" -> "Integer"}, FactorInteger[#x] &];
URLFetch["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/66b35b10-0f8e-4be4-bbdc-7ee3f6fbf82a", "Parameters" -> {"x" -> "1"}]
```

gives

[image]

Api's are not generally meant to be used by logging in and manipulating elements in a web page. I"m sure this is possible and I'm just missing something.

Comment: You have to make the API public, if it's not public then it redirects you to a login form because when you send the request with cURL/`URLFetch` like that it cannot know who you are. That HTML is probably for the login form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploy your API with public permissions or add Username and Password options to URLFetch:

```
With[{cloudobject = FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory, "FactorIntegerAPI"}]}, 
   CloudDeploy[
      APIFunction[{"x" -> "Integer"}, FactorInteger[#x] &],
      cloudobject, Permissions -> "Public"]; 
   URLFetch[URLBuild[cloudobject, {"x" -> "1"}]]]
```